# What does system.import do?

Tags: javascript, angular, systemjs

I have the below code in my `index.html`, basically what does the app represents? Does it `map` it to `folder`?

```
   System.import('app').catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
   });
```

Does the `app` has any relation to the `map or packages` object?

```
var map = {
    'app': 'dist', // 'dist',
    '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
    'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs'
};
// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
var packages = {
    'app': {
        main: 'main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'rxjs': {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
};
```

Comment: you may find this helpful : https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs

Comment: `System.import()` is a polyfill for [dynamic import](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) proposal, `app` is a module name, SystemJS uses `map` and `packages` in its config file to determine actual URL for loading `app` module.